# No error message displayed for custom validator

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a requirement that one of multiple fields is required.  Using custom validator the even fires, false is returned, but no error message is display and the form validates.

What am I missing?  I have tried with and without ValidationSummary.

Thanks!

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" OnServerValidate="validatePhone" EnableClientScript="false" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Home or Cell Phone is Required" ></asp:CustomValidator>

<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" DisplayMode="BulletList"  runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="X-Small" Font-Bold="true" />


protected void validatePhone(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
    {
        e.IsValid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCellPhone.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtHomePhone.Text) ? false : true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was completely my fault.  On my submit button the final thing I do is a Response.Redirect.   The message was coming up, but then the Thank you page was being presented.  Now only doing the Response.Redirect if the customvalidator returns true.

Comment: You should only do process the code if `Page.IsValid = true`. That checks all validators in the ValidationGroup are valid. Otherwise you can bypass validation by messing with the JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the ControlToValidate to some TextBox.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" OnServerValidate="validatePhone" EnabEnableClientScript="false" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Home or Cell Phone is Required" ControlToValidate="txtHomePhone"/>
```

Comment: Setting ControlToValidate will not validate if the control is empty.  Since I am validating multiple controls this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/MultiDependValidator.aspx). Basically you need to wire up the client side validation.
Add the following just before the closing form tag changing the control names as needed:

```
<%-- This configures the validator to automatically--%> 
<%-- update when either of these controls is changed --%>
<script type="text/javascript">
   <!--
      ValidatorHookupControlID("<%= MyControl1.ClientID %>", 
      document.getElementById["<%= CustomValidator1.ClientID %>"]);
      ValidatorHookupControlID("<%= MyControl2.ClientID %>", 
      document.getElementById["<%= CustomValidator1.ClientID %>"]);
   //-->
</script>
```

Alternatively use [this control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/MultipleFieldsValidator.aspx)